# How can redirect the users when they trying to edit a post from the frontend to /$post-type/$post-id/edit

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How can redirect the users whenever they trying to edit a post from the frontend to /$post-type/$post-id/edit

Comment: you can get the link with `get_edit_post_link`  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/

Comment: I've read the answers of this question but I didn't understand how can I use it in the frontend side.. that code is helpful if you want to change the link or the template in the admin panel to a custom one

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
global $post;
$type = $post->post_type;
$id = $post->ID;
echo '<a href="/' . $type . '/' . $id . '/edit' . '">Edit post</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer by using the

```
add_rewrite_rule()
```

example:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
      'checklists/([a-z0-9-]+)/(edit)/?$',
      'index.php?checklist_slug=$matches[1]&checklist_action=$matches[2]',
      'top'
  );
});
```

and then pass the parameters to the `query_var` by applying a filter using `query_var` hook

```
add_filter('query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
  $query_vars[] = "checklist_slug";
  $query_vars[] = "checklist_action";
  return $query_vars;
});
```

and lastly, assign a custom template to the `query_var` using the `template_include` hook

```
add_action( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
  if ( (get_query_var( 'checklist_slug' ) == false || get_query_var( 'checklist_slug' ) == '') && (get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == false || get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == '')) {
      return $template;
  }
  if ( get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == 'edit' ) {
    return get_template_directory() . '/includes/checklist_edit.php';
  } 
  if ( get_query_var( 'checklist_action' ) == 'new-checklist' ) {
    return get_template_directory() . '/includes/checklist_create.php';
  }
});
```

WordPress documentaion: [add_rewrite_rule()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)